# Reverse mapping from qubit Hamiltonian to fermionic operator

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation

I'm just wondering if there is an algorithm to do reverse mapping of a Hamiltonian on qubit basis to fermionic operator in Fock space, assuming we know the mapping rule (e.g. Jordan-Wigner).

Comment: Jordan–Wigner transformation as far as I know was originally created to do the opposite, map spins into fermions. Most books on second quantization go this path.

Comment: I think I solved my own problem. Openfermion has a function called reverse_jordan_wigner that has that function

Comment: you can submit an answer to your own question but you should edit the question to specify that you were looking for a solution in Qiskit